# {{array.value}} from localstorage not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, ionic2

Im currently building a simple email form using ionic 2. So there is a form where you will fill all subject, message and font. After filling in the form, Ill put it in @ionic/storage as an object. You can see it on the diagram below:

[image: ionic localstorage]

Now, on the next page, I tried to get the item data using these codes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Component({
  selector: 'preview-email-page',
  templateUrl: 'preview-email.html',
})
export class PreviewEmailPage {
  loading: any;
  personalizeData: any[];

  constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public localStorage: Storage,
  ) {
    this.localStorage.get('personalizeData').then((value) => {
      this.personalizeData = value;
    })
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log(this.ecardData);
  }
```

The console log does show that the data are correctly fetched from the local ionic storage. The console.log output this:

[image: console.log pic]

The problem occur when I want to display the value in the html page:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      <span>Personalize {{personalizeData.subject}}</span>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The html page will not be accessible with the following warning in console log:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./PreviewEmailPage class PreviewEmailPage - inline template:6:12 caused by: Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me find the reason for the error? Really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `personalizeData` is not defined at the moment of template rendering, use safe navigation operator (`?`) to avoid this error:

```
<span>Personalize {{personalizeData?.subject}}</span>
```

Read more about safe navigation operator [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).